# Django password reset form

Tags: python, django, passwords, reset

I'd like users to be be able to reset their passwords via a link on my site. I'm trying to use the built in django password reset form, but having a little difficulty. I have the following included in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/password_reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name='admin_password_reset'),
    url(r'^admin/password_reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

I access the link in the following way:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot your password?</a></h3>
```

I've also tried including it like this:

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uid, token %}
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
```

I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/
Reverse for 'password_reset' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I've tried a bunch of different tings without any luck. Do I need to pass in the uid/token? If so, how do I define them?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is named `admin_password_reset`

`<h3><a href="{% url 'admin_password_reset' %}">Forgot your password?</a></h3>`

Comment: That did it! Though I did need the quotes around the url name. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to an issue I had.  You might check my solution: [Django {% url %} reverse not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039050/django-url-reverse-not-working/10039561#10039561) if you are using {% load url from future %}.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks -- that helped some I think. I updated the error messages and code to match